# Trying to pass a Base64 string as a Byte

Tags: c#

Please help.  I need to pass 3 values to a webservice:

- `RptDate(string)`,
- `UserID(string)`,
- `PassHash(base64Binary)`

This `PassHash` is what's giving me the problem, because **PassHash is supposed to be the UserID and Password concatenated together(`UserIDPassword`), then calculating a binary MD5 hash of this value, then converting this hash value to a Base64 decoded string.**  My C# code below shows an example of what I have so far.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string UnameVal = "BSimpson";
    string PwordVal = "Springfield";
    string ReportDate = "2015-12-25";
    string source = string.Concat(UnameVal, PwordVal);
    string hashed = getMd5Hash2(source);
    byte[] ph1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hashed);

//Build Hyperlink...
         var sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.AppendFormat("https://ExampleService/GetRptLength?ReportDate={0}&UserID={1}&PassHash={2}", ReportDate, UnameVal, ph1);
     HyperLink1.Visible = true;
     HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = sb.ToString();
}

static string getMd5Hash2(string input) {
    // Create a new instance of the MD5CryptoServiceProvider object.
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5Hasher = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

    // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash.
    byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input));

    // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes
    // and create a string.
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    // Loop through each byte of the hashed data 
    // and format each one as a hexadecimal string.
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) {
        sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
    }

    // Return the hexadecimal string.
    return sBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Here is [the result](https://ExampleService/GetRptLength?ReportDate=2015-12-25&UserID=AdminReport&PassHash=System.Byte[]) of building the hyperlink.

When I submit this link, it states that I have an "*Invalid Password Hash Value*".  Isn't there supposed to be a value for `PassHash` instead of just `System.Byte[]`?  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to take your byte array and convert it to a base64 string, as a byte array won't have a valid representation given by it's `.ToString()` method.

You can do this with the following:

```
var passwordHashInBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(ph1);
```

Then just pass the `passwordHashInBase64` to your string builder instead of `ph1`.

Edit:

Looking more closely at your code, it seems like you're taking an extra step in general here. In your getMd5Hash2 function, after this line:

`byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input));`

add
`return System.Convert.ToBase64String(data);`

and remove the stringbuilder/hexadecimal representation.

Then, in your submit event, don't worry about getting the bytes from `hashed` and just pass in that string as your hash value.

`sb.AppendFormat("https://ExampleService/GetRptLength?ReportDate={0}&UserID={1}&PassHash={2}", ReportDate, UnameVal, hashed);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Willem.  When I tried your solution though, I get the error below because the service is looking for "PassHash" as a Byte[]: "The best overloaded method for 'ExampleService/GetRptLength(string, string, byte[])' has some invalid arguments"  How do I send that 'hashed' value as a Byte[] now?

Comment: Do you control the endpoint? You should change the expected value for PassHash to a string, which you could then get the bytes from with `System.Convert.FromBase64String`

Comment: No, I do not control the endpoint.  However, I did find out from the author of the webservice that I need to hash the data as SHA256 and not MD5.  So here is my updated code://-----For SHA256 Hash--------------------------------------------------
            string hashed = Base64SHA256(source);
            byte[] ph1 = Convert.FromBase64String(hashed);
            //pass parms to GetReportLength Web Service
            int a = RptLnth.GetReportLength(ReportDate, UnameVal, ph1);
            Label5.Text = "Rpt Length is " + a.ToString(); 
...but it still does not work...!